# Unable to go out of wait method

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, synchronized

I'm working on a simple program that sorts an integer array of 10 elements into another array of the same length. To do this, I create 10 threads and each one is responsible to take its number from the source array and put it into the right position in the new array.

I have an abstract class *SortThread* which implements *Runnable*. I have also two subclasses which extend the class above, *SuperSortThread* (initializes the source array, sorts its number and prints out the array) and *SimpleSortThread* (only sorts its number). I'm trying to lock the source array while the "super thread" initializes the array. Then, I free the lock. At last, I have a main class which create and start the threads.

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class SortThread implements Runnable {

    private final int tNumber;
    static int[] source = new int[10];
    static int[] dest;

    public SortThread(int tNumber) {
        this.tNumber = tNumber;
    }

    public final int lessThan() {
    /* Calculates the number of elements of source
         less than myNumber */

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            if (source[tNumber] > source[i])
                count++;

        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract void run();
}
```

---

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class SuperSortThread extends SortThread {

    private int tNumber;   

    public SuperSortThread(int tNumber) {
        super(tNumber);
        this.tNumber = tNumber;

    }

    private static void printArray(int[] number) {

        System.out.print("\nVector: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.print(number[i] + " ");

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (source) {

            source[0] = 5;
            source[1] = 7;
            source[2] = 6;
            source[3] = 3;
            source[4] = 8;
            source[5] = 9;
            source[6] = 4;
            source[7] = 0;
            source[8] = 1;
            source[9] = 2;

            dest = new int[10];
            source.notifyAll();

            printArray(source);

            int myNumber = source[tNumber];
            dest[lessThan()] = myNumber;

            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Error in Sleep.");
            }

            printArray(dest);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SimpleSortThread extends SortThread {

    private int tNumber;

    public SimpleSortThread(int tNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        super(tNumber);
        this.tNumber = tNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (source) {
            try {
                source.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Wait error in simple thread");
            }

            int myNumber = source[tNumber];
            dest[lessThan()] = myNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, "simple threads" get permanently locked in wait. What could it be?

Comment: Maybe your `SuperSortThread.run()` is call before `SimpleSortThread.run()`. So you enter in wait() but task is already done and notifyAll() was lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `SuperSortThread` runs before the `SimpleSortThread` (or more specifically `source.notifyAll();` runs before `source.wait();`) then by the time you try to wait, nothing is left to notify you. You will wait forever.

This is called a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You should probably set a flag after you notify, to tell the other thread that you notified already so that it won't wait.

Also, `SimpleSortThread` is dependant on `SuperSortThread`. You cannot run it without it.

Lastly, and possibly most importantly, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with `wait` and `notify` here? I don't see what you want it do.

Comment: I belief than notifyAll would wake up threads that weren't in wait zone yet. I fixed it changing the order of sync calls and getting the synchronous block closer.

Answer (score 0):

Comment - It will definately wait.  you are notifying from SuperSortThread and again you are waiting on simpleSortThread. You can wait for something to be true like

```
while(flag){ source.wait()}
```

And set the value of flag from other thread.

 You wait for something to happen, then if that happens , you start executing some task. You are waiting for nothing